# Sublime Text 2 tab_size setting not correctly activated

Tags: sublimetext2

I have the following in my `user/Preferences.sublime-settings`

```
{
    "tab_size": 2,
}
```

And most of the time it works.  But once in a while I open a ruby file, and it jumped back to 4 spaces.  I'm wondering if there is some bug or slight difference in opening a file that could change this?

Having trouble tracking this down.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14):

You'll want to add:

```
"detect_indentation": false
```

This is on by default and ST is trying to be smart detecting the indentation of your current file, overloading the user or syntax specific default.

Answer (score 7):

Here are various Sublime Text 2 tab settings explained:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Configure_sane_tab_and_whitespace_policy_and_other_settings

- Note that the tab setting may be per file type
- There is also autodetect from file enabled by default and your source code file may contain bad tabbing

Comment: the auto-detect feature was my problem. my second line was indented 4 spaces by mistake so the tab size switched to 4. fixed the indentation and my problem was solved.